# Why occur View can not be anchored to the the parent CoordinatorLayout on android?

Tags: android

I want use `CoordinatorLayout` 
but occur

`IllegalStateException : View can not be anchored to the the parent CoordinatorLayout`

first I add `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'` on gradle.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--<include layout="@layout/base_toolbar"/>-->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toDoEmptyView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/main_memo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/main_text"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        >

        <include layout="@layout/base_toolbar"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<include layout="@layout/base_toolbar"/>-->


    <!--</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>-->


    <hyunwook.co.kr.memoalarm.RecyclerViewEmptySupport
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/toDoRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:src="@drawable/add_floating"
        android:id="@+id/addToDoItemFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/myCoordinatorLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:layout_behavior="hyunwook.co.kr.memoalarm.ScrollingFABBehaviour"
        />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Why occur IllegalStateException ?

thanks.

Comment: set CoordinatorLayout at parent in layout

Answer (score 0):

Use parent Layout as `CoordinatorLayout` not a `LinearLayout`. and put your whole code inside `CoordinatorLayout`